# Call method and send array data from view to component in Angular ngFor loop

Tags: angular, firebase, ngfor

I have an ngFor loop that is going through an array and outputting data to the View, which is working great. However, one of the items is the path to an image and I need to send that image path to a method in the component that retrieves the image from Googles Firebase Storage. Here is one of several attempts that would not work

SEND IMAGEPATH VALUE FROM RP ARRAY TO COMPONENT AND RUN METHOD ONLOADFILE

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{rp.imagePath}}" ng-change="onLoadFile($event.target.value)">
```

HERE IS THE METHOD THAT CALLS THE FILE IN FIREBASE STORAGE

```
onLoadFile($event) {
  this.downloadURL = this.afStorage.ref(event).getDownloadURL();
}
```

HERE IS THE VIEW THAT DISPLAYS THE IMAGE LOADED BY THE METHOD

```
<div *ngIf="downloadURL | async; let url">
    <img [src]="url">
</div>
```

The method and the image display items both work. I simply cannot find a way to call the method and send it the required data. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

From this it looks like what you are trying to do is to pass imagePath when the url changes. If that is the case, I think one way to do that is, change that to an `ngModel` and then use `(ngModelChange)` and pass your function to that.

Comment: For some reason I'm not able to bind using ngModel on a hidden input field.

Comment: Plawan thank you for trying to help me out here. It seems silly now, but I realized the full path of the images had to be inserted into the array that was being displayed in the view before displaying it. For others struggling with this problem, you can't add them to the View during ngFor because they'll just overwrite themselves and put you in an endless loop.